# Configuring shortcuts for Sakura

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sakura

I am massively confused by the sakura terminal emulator's .conf file. I want to make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> open a new tab and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> close a tab. I have tried:

```
add_tab_key=alt+;
add_tab_key=alt-;
add_tab_key=;
```

None of these seem to work. In fact no control key combination works, and only certain single keys work. The default is `add_tab_key=T` and if I leave it as this I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. However I changed fullscreen to `fullscreen_key=F` and now it goes fullscreen if I press either <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

I'm using sakura on Lubuntu 13.10 running i3wm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two settings you need to change: `add_tab_key` *and* `add_tab_accelerator` (same for the other shortcuts).

The `foo_key` *relatively* is straightforward - you need to put the key name there. For letters, just put the letter you want in the case you want it. Same for digits. For anything else, you need to look at the names defined in `gdkkeysyms.h` and find the one you want (the man page has a link for that file if you don't have it somewhere under `/usr/include` on your system). Note that the name is **case sensitive**.

The `foo_accelerator` is a bitmask of values defined in the `gdktypes.h` header (`GdkModifierType` enum).

Here's what I have on my system:

```
typedef enum
{
  GDK_SHIFT_MASK    = 1 << 0,
  GDK_LOCK_MASK     = 1 << 1,
  GDK_CONTROL_MASK  = 1 << 2,
  GDK_MOD1_MASK     = 1 << 3,
  GDK_MOD2_MASK     = 1 << 4,
  GDK_MOD3_MASK     = 1 << 5,
  GDK_MOD4_MASK     = 1 << 6,
  GDK_MOD5_MASK     = 1 << 7,
  GDK_BUTTON1_MASK  = 1 << 8,
  GDK_BUTTON2_MASK  = 1 << 9,
  GDK_BUTTON3_MASK  = 1 << 10,
  GDK_BUTTON4_MASK  = 1 << 11,
  GDK_BUTTON5_MASK  = 1 << 12,

  /* The next few modifiers are used by XKB, so we skip to the end.
   * Bits 15 - 25 are currently unused. Bit 29 is used internally.
   */

  GDK_SUPER_MASK    = 1 << 26,
  GDK_HYPER_MASK    = 1 << 27,
  GDK_META_MASK     = 1 << 28,

  GDK_RELEASE_MASK  = 1 << 30,

  GDK_MODIFIER_MASK = 0x5c001fff
} GdkModifierType;
```

According to `xmodmap`, my `Alt_L` key is modifier one. `MOD1_MASK` is `1<<3`, i.e. 8. So if I want <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> to open a new tab, I need this in my configuration:

```
add_tab_accelerator=8
add_tab_key=plus
```

If I wanted <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>, then (`CONTROL_MASK` is `1<<2`, i.e. 4):

```
add_tab_accelerator=4
add_tab_key=8
```

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, you add the modifier values:

```
add_tab_accelerator=12
add_tab_key=t
```

Comment: To save others some googleing, Lubuntu doesn't have a gdkkeysyms.h by default and the package libgtk-3-dev needs to be installed (it will create it at /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkkeysyms.h). Also "<<" is the [left shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift)  operator and this [calculator](http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/bit-shift/?data_type=10&number=1&place=3&operator=Shift+Left) will do the calculations for you.

Comment: Alas, the Lubuntu gdkkeysyms.h is all commented out and the values given are all in hex and don't seem to work.

Comment: The thing you take from gdkkeysyms.h is the _name_ of the key, not the hex value. I.e. "+" after searching a bit in there is `#define GDK_KEY_plus 0x02b`, so the key you need to put in the config file is "plus".

Comment: @Mat: Do you know, how to use the Super-key in a shortcut? I already ask the question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114725/shortcuts-for-sakura but unfortunately there was no really helpful answer

Comment: @samcarter: did you try 67108864 as add_tab_accelerator value? (That's `1<<26`). Also try 64 (for mod4).

Comment: @Mat: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Using 67108864 or 64 as add_tab_accelerator results in shift+super+t. Is there a way to just get super+t ?