# Shortcuts for sakura

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sakura

How can I configure shortcuts for a sakura terminal?

I know about the question [Configuring shortcuts for Sakura](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102474/60134) but I did not success.

---

In the end I would like to have

- copy: <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
- paste: <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
- cut: <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
- new terminal: <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
- fullscreen: <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

---

If I try to reproduce [Mat's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102481/60134)

> According to xmodmap, my `Alt_L` key is modifier one. `MOD1_MASK is 1<<3`,
>   i.e. 8. So if I want <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> to open a new tab, I need this in my
>   configuration:
>
> ```
> add_tab_accelerator=8 
> add_tab_key=t
> ```

it results in the shortcut <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> instead of <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>. Can anyone help?

---

In case it is hepfull, here is what `xmodmap` gives:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Comment: what do you want crtl or super ? because you first mention one and then another. also copy accelerator should be 26 not 4 if I understand well and never overwrite crtl+c you will need it in a terminal

Comment: I would like to have super, but I first tried crtl, because this was mentioned in the question I put the link.

Comment: using 26 for `copy_accelerator` does not give a working shortcut